# When should wildcards be inside / outside double quotes?

Tags: bash, wildcard, rm

What is the correct way to use a wild card and a variable to delete many files? This is my variable `"$dir"`

```
$ echo "$dir"
/home/path/to/file
```

Here I have the wild card inside the double quotes, but it does not work:

```
$ rm "$dir/data/ffg_per_product/ffg*"
rm: cannot remove `/home/path/to/file/data/ffg_per_product/ffg*': No such file or directory
```

Here I have the wildcard outside the double quotes and it works:

```
$ rm "$dir/data/ffg_per_product/ffg"*
```

And here you can see the files were deleted:

```
$ ls -lth ffg_per_product/ffg* | wc -l
ls: cannot access ffg_per_product/ffg*: No such file or directory
0
```

**So what I want to know, is am I using the quotes correctly to delete the files `rm "$dir/data/ffg_per_product/ffg"*` with the wildcard outise the quotes? Or is there another/better way?**

**NOTE:** probably obvious to some but just for refererence and to be clear, the same applies for `ls` e.g. `ls "$dir/data/ffg_per_product/NAME"* | wc -l`, in that, does the wild card have to be outside the double quotes.

Comment: Related, with much more context in the answers; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Answer (score 3):

A `*` outside of quotes is expanded by the shell to matching filenames.

A `*` inside quotes is not expanded, it is used literally, just a simple `*`.

This is correct and corresponds to your intention:

```
rm "$dir/data/ffg_per_product/ffg"*
```

The same goes for your other example with the `ls` command too,
exactly the same reasoning.